# Redirect to Login page if ther user not logged in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel version 5. I have a route file for my project which contains plenty of lines. I need to put authentication like Redirect to login page if the user is not logged in. And I also want to prevent direct URL access if the user not logged in. What can I do?

And I have used below code

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

But this prevents only for home page. I need to protect All my routes. And also suggest me how to reduce route file lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put as many routes in a Group as you like to

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('store', 'HomeController@store');
    Route::get('show', 'AnotherController@index');
    // ...
});
```

If you really need to protect **all** your routes, you could add

```
 public function __construct()
 {
      $this->middleware('auth');
 }
```

To your main controller class, `Http/Controllers/Controller`

Edit for your comment, taken from the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication), you may use

> return redirect()->intended('view');

```
/**
 * Handle an authentication attempt.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Then there is another error you did not describe. Check your laravel.log in storage/logs for errors maybe

Comment: I have checked logs file. It seems no error regarding my issue.

Comment: But your second __construct function works perfectly. I want to know which method is best?

Comment: I want to know one thing. Is there any way to redirect last accessed url after login?

Comment: how i use authentication in modules